# Last Year’s YTD Number query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need help getting the count of records for last year's YTD.

To get the records for this YTD numbers I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(columnname) 
FROM *** 
where "columnname" BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE() 
AND user_code IN ('0410', '0411')) as Ag
```

This give the total records for 01/01/2016-06/02/2016 (today's date) which is right now I need to get the same total but for last's YTD it would be for **01/01/2015-06/02/2015** please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, in both places where you have `GETDATE()`, just replace with `DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())`

```
WHERE [someColumn] BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())), 0) AND DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
```